# How to redirect stdout from docker container to host

Tags: mysql, docker, go

I'm trying to call docker's mysqldump from host system for save mysql dump from golang. It works correctly with host mysqldump, but don't work with docker's mysqldump.

```
func writeDb(dbName string)
{
   var mysqldumpPath string = "/usr/bin/mysqldump"
 //var mysqldumpPath string = "/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqldump"

 //cmd := exec.Command(mysqldumpPath, fmt.Sprintf("-u%s", USER), fmt.Sprintf("-p%s", PASSWORD) , dbName)
   cmd := exec.Command("docker", "exec", "some-mysql", mysqldumpPath, fmt.Sprintf("%s", USER), fmt.Sprintf("-p%s", PASSWORD) , dbName, ">", fmt.Sprintf("%s.sql", dbName))

   stdout, err := cmd.StdoutPipe()
   if err != nil
   {
     log.Fatal(err)
   }

   if err := cmd.Start(); err != nil
   {
     log.Fatal(err)
   }

   bytes, err := ioutil.ReadAll(stdout)
   if err != nil
   {
      log.Fatal(err)
   }
   err = ioutil.WriteFile("./backup/" + dbName +".sql", bytes, 0644)
   if err != nil
   {
     panic(err)
   }
```

}

I got only that for non-empty database
[empty mysql dump](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xj9k0.png)

Comment: You are doing exec and redirecting output to a file and then expecting the data to be on stdout also, this won't work. You should use one either stdout or redirection

Comment: Did you resolve your issue? Because you did select my answer...

Comment: Yes, i sloved the problem, but with another way, i'll post the solution in my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is:

```
func writeDb(dbName string) {
var mysqldumpPath string = "/usr/bin/mysqldump"
cmd := exec.Command("docker", "exec", "some-mysql", mysqldumpPath, "-u", fmt.Sprintf("%s", USER), fmt.Sprintf("-p%s", PASSWORD) , fmt.Sprintf("%s", dbName))

stdout, err := cmd.StdoutPipe()
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}

if err := cmd.Start(); err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}

bytes, err := ioutil.ReadAll(stdout)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
err = ioutil.WriteFile("./backup/" + dbName +".sql", bytes, 0644)
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
```

}

Just without "> dbname.sql"

Comment: Nice, but don't forget to accept your own answer (and don't accept other answers too soon ;-) )

Answer (score 2):

Instead of mysql, try a simple command like :

- `pwd`
- `echo a > b`, just to see if you do see a file `b` on your host.

You need to make that redirection inside the container in a folder which has been mounted from the host (**[using volume](https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/volumes/volumes)**), in order for the created file to persists, once docker exec exits the container.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:**

The OP doesn't work inside `go` code. It gives an error: `the input device is not a TTY`. I will try to find out why and update the post...

---

**OP:**

What about using `docker exec -it [command]`

Example:

```
# start a new mysql container...
$ docker run --rm -d --name="test_mysql" -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root mysql

# mysqldump > stdout
$ docker exec -it test_mysql mysqldump -u root -proot sys
```

or

```
# mysqldump > stdout > file
$ docker exec -it test_mysql mysqldump -u root -proot sys > sys.sql
```

Comment: I got the empty mysqldump output. With no symbols. You command works well, but in golang code isn't