# How can you get output from inside a cmd container?

Tags: docker

I’m setting up a basic docker container which contains a  server.js script inside my-app folder.

My dockerfile looks like this:

```
#Use node parent image
FROM node:9.6.1

#Set the working directory to /my-app
WORKDIR /my-app


# Make port 80 available to the world outside this container
EXPOSE 80


cmd pwd
RUN npm install


# start app
CMD node server.js
```

The server.js file is not found and I'm trying to debug this by printing pwd to the terminal. I get the error when server.js file cannot be found, but CMD pwd seems to be ignored. How can I print in the container to find out why server.js cannot be executed?

Comment: I do not understand this Line `cmd pwd`

Comment: Also your WORKDIR /my-app needs that folder already created...

Comment: cmd pwd is to get the path where the next cmd commend will be executed

Comment: CMD doesn't produce any output.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37461868/whats-the-difference-between-run-and-cmd-in-a-docker-file-and-when-should-i-use/37462208#37462208

Comment: Possibly related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46356999/how-to-redirect-stdout-from-docker-container-to-host and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34632959/redirecting-command-output-in-docker. The second one seems to be a solution you'd be interested in.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `docker run yourcontainername` to start your container (if it is stopped) to see what goes wrong.

If your container keeps running (which it probably doesn't) you can go into the container using `docker exec -it yourcontainername bash` and figure out what goes wrong.

**ps:** you are probably missing the following in your Dockerfile: `COPY server.js /my-app/`

Comment: The thing is that Dockerfiles should normally only have one CMD command. (because Docker containers should only manage 1 process) You could add something like `RUN echo $HOME` in the Dockerfile, then build it. During building you will get the output that pwd would otherwise give you.

Answer (score 0):

Change Dockerfile to:

```
FROM node:9.6.1
RUN mkdir -p /my-app
WORKDIR /my-app
COPY . /my-app
RUN npm install
EXPOSE 80
CMD node server.js
```